# Laravel String to Array of Int

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel 7.

I have a return from eloquent like this:

```
$menu_roles_parent = MenuRoles::where('role_id',1)->pluck('pai_id');
```

that return me a string like this : ["15,19"].
The problem is that i wanna use this return on my next eloquent query , for example :

```
$menus = \App\Menu::whereIn('id',$menu_roles_parent)->with('submenus')->where('active',1)->orderBy('position')->get();
```

the query run , but i wanna change this below :

```
select * from 'menus' where 'id' in ('15,19') and 'active' = 1 order by 'position' asc
```

to

```
select * from 'menus' where 'id' in (15,19) and 'active' = 1 order by 'position' asc
```

i am thinking in put the string return in a array of integers ,someone could help me ? thanks.

Comment: Did one of the answers fix your problem, or do you still have issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) native php function to explode a string into array splitted by delimiter.

```
$menu_roles_parent = explode(",", $menu_roles_parent[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you casts your columns, it will automatically cast it using Eloquent `pluck()`. Adding casts to your model like this, should solve your problem.

```
class MenuRoles {
    protected $casts = [
        'role_id' => 'int',
    ];
}
```